# Want to set storyboard target property as horizontal offset of a scrollviewer

Tags: windows-phone-7, c#-4.0, silverlight-4.0, windows-phone-7.1

I am using scroll viewer in my app which shows images in a horizontal view. I need to use animation while scrolling like in this video how to acheive this

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XVHVBMeqL24

I have tried this

```
   public Storyboard CreateAndApplyStoryboard(UIElement targetElement)
    {

        Storyboard sb = new Storyboard();


        DoubleAnimation animation =
            new DoubleAnimation { From = 0, To = 500, Duration = new Duration(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1.0)) };

        //ExponentialEase ese = new ExponentialEase();
        //ese.EasingMode = EasingMode.EaseIn;
        //animation.EasingFunction = ese;
        Storyboard.SetTarget(animation, targetElement);
        Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(animation,
            new PropertyPath(ScrollViewer.HorizontalOffsetProperty));



        sb.Children.Add(animation);
        return sb;
    }
```

I am just showing the example i need to scroll from horizontal offset 0 to 500

How to use the dependency property?

```
  <scrollviewer name="scroll">
  <StackPanel Name="stack" Width="5000" Orientation="Horizontal"  HorizontalAlignment="Left" >
        <StackPanel.RenderTransform>
                <TranslateTransform x:Name="Trans2" X="0" Y="0" />
            </StackPanel.RenderTransform>
    </StackPanel>
```

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {                                 
            Storyboard sb = CreateAndApplyStoryboard(scroll);
            sb.Begin();

        }
```

Comment: so what is your problem? Yor `From` and `To` is the same

Comment: I am just showing the example i need to scroll from horizontal offset 0 to 500.I have to animate while scrolling like the video link. I am using this method but i dont know how to animate help me

Comment: Then you neet to set From to 0 and To to 500

Comment: i tried but not works i need another best example i have tried a lot to animate the horizontal offset but i cant.

Comment: you do start the storyboard somewhere?

Comment: private void button1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {                                 
                Storyboard sb = CreateAndApplyStoryboard(scroll);
                sb.Begin();
              
            }
    i need to scroll when click the button.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/10217/discussion-between-senthil-kumar-and-pivotnig)